# Retrieve images from Parse along its geolocation

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, mkannotationview, pfquery

I get geolocations for annotations on map and would like to show user related image from the same row in a custom view.

I've tried saving PFFiles in a dictionary along with ObjectIDs because I'm setting each annotation's title its location's ObjectID but that gives me - *[PFObject objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance*.

This is what I'm currently doing.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"photoObject"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){

        for (id object in objects) {


            [self.annotationArray addObject:object[@"location"]];
            NSLog(@"Annotation's coordinate : %@", self.annotationArray);

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:object[@"photo"]];

            [self.imageFileDict setObject:object[@"photo"] forKey:[object objectID]];
            NSLog(@"imageFileDict : %@", self.imageFileDict);

            self.geoPoint = object[@"location"];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.geoPoint.latitude, self.geoPoint.longitude);
            CustomPin *pin = [[CustomPin alloc] initWithTitle:[object objectId] location:locCoord image:image];
            [self.mainMap addAnnotation:pin];

            NSLog(@"Adding annotation");


        }

    }];
```

And then

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

CustomPin *pin = (CustomPin *)[view annotation];
NSLog(@"selected pin's objectID : %@",pin.title);

UIImageView *callOutview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width)];
[self.view addSubview:callOutview];
callOutview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

callOutview.image = pin.image;}
```

**Edit**

I've realized I had to do this in order to make it work with PFFiles

```
PFFile *imageFile = object[@"photo"];
            [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    self.callOutImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


                }}];
```

But still not working.

Comment: try this first: change this  for (id object in objects) { to this for (PFObject * object in objects) {    then show the result

Comment: Yep, I tried all variations, and you are right, it doesn't work yet

Answer (score 1):

Solved it..

```
PFFile *imageFile = object[@"photo"];
            [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {

                    [self.annotationArray addObject:object[@"location"]];
                    NSLog(@"Annotation's coordinate : %@", self.annotationArray);


                    self.callOutImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                    self.geoPoint = object[@"location"];

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.geoPoint.latitude, self.geoPoint.longitude);
                    CustomPin *pin = [[CustomPin alloc] initWithTitle:[object objectId] location:locCoord image:self.callOutImage];
                    [self.mainMap addAnnotation:pin];

                }}];
```

I had to set the images inside getDataInBackgroundWithBlock since I'm getting PFFiles for UIImages in background otherwise images get no data.